# Android: Automatic User Locatio

Tags: android, eclipse, dictionary, location

I am working on the developement of an android app. I need to locate the user without displaying the map (only the name of his location ei New york, USA) 
I work using Eclipse SDK. 
Is there a way to do it? 
Thanks :)
Ps: I am new to android

Comment: I tried this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ 
It works but it gives me latitude and longitude when I actually need the name of the location..

Comment: See below. Android's GeoCoder class will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Android API Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker)
In the API documentation it shows you step by step how to get started on this
type of application.
[How to get started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

One thing you have to remember is that the user must enable
the GPS to get current location

Answer (score 0):

Since you explained in comments that you already know how to get the `Location`, and thus the latitude and longitude, you can resolve it to an address using Android's [`GeoCoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class, with its [`getFromLocation(double,double,int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29) method.